# How do i reorganize my php code to include separate db info file

Tags: php, mysql

Can any of you guys help me to reorganize this code? I'll try to explain the problem below.

I have a db_connection.php wich includes the following (just my db info and don't worry, i am just using it locally):

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webappeind;charset=utf8','root','');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

But the problem is i have the following file that also includes my db info, but i do not know how to reorganize my code to get it working with my separate php file.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "webappeind";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM zoekopdrachten ORDER BY titel DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output gegevens van elke rij
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div class='recenttoegevoegd'>"."<a href='#'>".$row["titel"]."</a>"."</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 resultaten";
    }
?>
```

Comment: So you want to play pick-a-mix with PDO and MySQLi?

Comment: Normally you need to initialize your connection in your application bootstrap (early at the beginning),  just use one global variable to store your connection to DB, then use it all over your application.

Comment: @MarkBaker no, i want to know how to do it correctly, because i think this is a mixture of all kind of things :)

Comment: Well to start with, pick one interface to use, either MySQLi or PDO, but not both, or a mix-and-match of the two

Comment: w3c gave me this example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the connection information in a separate file called, say, conn.php where you mention the code related to database opening, including credentials. Then, in the calling file, say putdata.php, you use the "require" or "require_once" command to include that conn.php. Let the conn.php file return a connection. Somewhat like this :

```
<?php
function GetMyConn() {
    $server_name = "localhost";
    $db_name = "db_name_goes_here";
    $db_user = "user_name_goes_here";
    $db_pass = "password_goes_here_muahhhaa";
    $db_full_addr = "mysql:host=" . $server_name . ";" . "dbname=" . $db_name;

    $MyConn = new PDO($db_full_addr, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $MyConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    return $MyConn;
}
?>
```

In the calling file, you would say, something like :

```
require_once "GetConn.php";

$MyConnHere = GetMyConn();
$SqlHere = "Sql Statemetn goes here...."
$SqlHere2 = $MyConnHere->prepare($SqlHere);
$SqlHere2->execute();
```

Also, I suggest you can download the source code of some open source PHP application, such as mantissa, and see how they have organized their code files, folders and settings.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i have a file called db_connection.php where all the info is what i need, but i do not get the code working when i include it :)

Comment: Your db_connection.php ( as found in the question text above) does not have a function that returns an established connection. Put the try-catch stuff inside a function and return the connection object that results from the connection attempt. 
In the calling file, invoke the function and get the resultant connection into a local connection variable. Like in my code above.